# Throwing error in Angular2 ngOnInit does not work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

When I have an error happen inside `ngOnInit()` that error seems to be bubbled up with an `TypeError: this._unregisterListenersFn is not a function` error instead.

Example:

```
constructor() {
   throw Error('error in constructor');
}
```

gives expected result in console window.
but in ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
   throw Error('error in ngOnInit')
}
```

gives first 'error in ngOnInit' as expected, but also

```
TypeError: this._unregisterListenersFn is not a function
```

I'm trying to handle all errors with an custom error handler, but when an error happens inside ngOnInit() I only get the latest error, and not the error causing the errors in the first place.

**Edit-follow-up:**
I think I've found the root cause in NgbPopover. The error Message shown in Chrome Developer Tools is:

```
TypeError: this._unregisterListenersFn is not a function
    at NgbPopover.webpackJsonp.../../../../@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.js.NgbPopover.ngOnDestroy (popover.js:128)
```

Comment: Do you get this in dev env?

Comment: I'm getting this behavior in both dev and prod environement.

Comment: Is there any listeners that you are trying to reach before ngOnInit because I started one angular 2 application with reproducing your scenario and it gives me the expected error.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time! Thanks to you I've traced the issue down to ng-bootstrap/ngbPopover that threw another error overriding my first error >.<

Comment: You are welcome!